# How to give the name to the child node in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever i will upload the data to the firebase it give random name to the child node. In the image "Upload" this name in given by me but what about inside name i want to change the name of inside the upload root how i can do that

[image: This is the image]

Comment: take a look at the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name inside the `Upload` is generated using `push()`, that you are using in your code, that is why you see it.

`push()` is a method that creates a random id to be able to seperate records in the database and also to be able to easily identify records in the Firebase Database.

push()

> Create a reference to an auto-generated child location. The child key is generated client-side and incorporates an estimate of the server's time for sorting purposes. Locations generated on a single client will be sorted in the order that they are created, and will be sorted approximately in order across all clients.

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()